# How to access a folder in remote host as spoiling directory path in flume

Tags: hadoop, logging, hdfs, flume, flume-ng

Here is my  `FlumeHadoop.conf` file.

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = spooldir
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sources.r1.spoolDir = /home/rabindra/idirectory 
a1.sources.r1.basenameHeader=true

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory

a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.byteCapacityBufferPercentage = 20
a1.channels.c1.byteCapacity = 131072000

a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1


# properties of k1-sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
#a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfs://namenode/flumesource/source1
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost/logdata
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix=%{basename}
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileSuffix=.txt
a1.sinks.k1.rollInterval=0
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.deletePolicy=immediate
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollSize=131072000
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollCount=0
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.idleTimeout=0
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.maxOpenFiles = 10000
```

In a remote host say, 192.168.7.43 and there is a directory **rdirectory** and the directory path  **/home/alex/rdirectory**.

I want to point the remote folder **rdirectory** as spoiling directory .
How it is possible?
I sm trying by this change

```
a1.sources.r1.spoolDir = alex@192.168.7.43:/home/alex/rdirectory
```

But this gives the exception *java.lang.IllegalStateException: Directory doesn't exists: /opt/flume/alex@192.168.7.43:/home/alex/rdirectory* .

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running this option

1. Run flume agent in 192.168.7.4
   Spool dir [source] --> netcat [sink]
2. Run flume agent in local machine 
   netcat [source] --> HDFS sink

Comment: But I want only run flume agent in local machine  not in the remote host where spoiling directory exists

Answer (score 0):

1.Install Samba on host 192.168.7.43, and config folder /home/alex/rdirectory can be interval by //192.168.7.43/rdirectory

2.Mount the share directory on flume agent host, than you can use mount directory like a local directory.

Here is an example mount directory on 192.168.59.166 to host H0045170
[image]